# django shell not detecting new module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-shell

Hello I have a django app name "celery_tasks" with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── apps.py
├── emitter
├── __init__.py
├── kse
├── mongo
```

I have added a new module name kse which contains two files:

```
├── __init__.py
├── lol.py
```

The `__init__.py` in the kse module contains `from .lol import lol`

And the lol.py file contains the following class:

```
class lol:

    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return True

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

The issue is that I cannot access the `kse` module via django shell:

```
>>> import celery_tasks
>>> celery_tasks.kse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'celery_tasks' has no attribute 'kse'
```

However the mongo and emmiter modules are accessible:

```
>>> celery_tasks.mongo
<module 'celery_tasks.mongo' from '/Users/kheshav/Linux_projects/rockynode.io/App/rockynode/celery_tasks/mongo/__init__.py'>
>>> celery_tasks.emitter
<module 'celery_tasks.emitter' from '/Users/kheshav/Linux_projects/rockynode.io/App/rockynode/celery_tasks/emitter/__init__.py'>
```

I have created the `kse` module in the same way i did for the mongo and emitter module but am not being able to access the kse module.

Did i missed something? Thank you

**Update 1**

As requested here is the `ls -la` of the directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  374 Oct 13 19:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root  476 Oct 12 22:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   98 Dec 11  2016 apps.py
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  170 Oct 12 19:56 emitter
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Oct 13 20:51 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  170 Oct 13 19:53 kse
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  204 Oct 12 19:56 mongo
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  102 Oct 13 20:50 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  170 Oct 12 22:51 zabbix
```

Comment: can you post a "ls -la" ouput of your directory?

Comment: I think you're confused about how imports work. Importing a package doesn't give you access to sub-packages; you need to import those directly (`from celery_tasks import kse`).

Comment: I didnt do `from celery_tasks import mongo` in the `__init__.py` but I was able to access mongo via `import celery_tasks; celery_tasks.mongo`. Only the kse module is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the module in the way you expect you should import `kse` inside `celery_tasks/__init__.py`

Comment: Importing the `kse` inside `celery_tasks/__init__.py` results in Django error: `raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")`

Comment: Ok, sorted the error out, had wrongly imported the module. Thanks